# elasticsearch: create index with mappings using javascript

Tags: elasticsearch, javascript

I'm trying to create an elasticsearch index with mappings using the official javascript client.

My code is as follows:

```js
client.indices.create({
    index: "aName",
    "mappings": {
        "aType": {
            "properties": {
                "aProp1": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
                "aProp2": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
                "aProp3": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
                "aProp4": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" }
            }
        }
    }
}, function(err,resp,respcode){
    console.log(err,resp,respcode);
});
```

However... the index is created but without the mappings....
The output is:

```
undefined { ok: true, acknowledged: true } 200
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ok.... found it after many trial/error attempts... Guess I need to wrap the mappings "block" in a "body" property. Documentation is still laggin behind :-(

Comment: Thanks. I think you should post your comment as an answer and mark it as correct. It's easy to miss comments on SO, plus you would probably gather some points :)

Comment: How do you know that your mapping doesn't exist? Could you show result of executing GET on `http://<host>:<port>/aName/_mapping/aType`?

Comment: Thanks Sander, The documentation for ES is pretty but also lacks necessary information.

Answer (score 33):

Refining the answer that is in the comment above from Sander Spilleman. The "mappings" property needs to be inside the "body" property. I am also using the Javascript client 1.3.0 and the docs are still not updated with an example.

Adding an example that worked for me with the javascript API provided by elasticsearch on NPM 1.3.0

```
var body = {
    tweet:{
        properties:{
            tag         : {"type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"},
            type        : {"type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"},
            namespace   : {"type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"},
            tid         : {"type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"}
        }
    }
}

client.indices.putMapping({index:"tweets", type:"tweet", body:body});
```

Comment: would you mind submitting a pull request or filling an issue for methods which you think would benefit from docs? I'd be happy to add them

Comment: @tim i think before put mapping we must call client.indices.create({
    index: "aName", type: "tweet", body:body, }, function(err,resp,respcode){
    console.log(err,resp,respcode);
}); otherwise they will get the error indexnotexistexception

Comment: @SpencerAlger What makes the ElasticSearch docs hard to use right now is there aren't any full examples in the client specific docs.  So I'm bouncing back and forth between the client docs and the generic API docs and it's basically guesswork to determine how to correctly map the parameters.

Answer (score 16):

I tried same but got error from the name of index. aName is not valid, error was about the using lowercase index name. Then It created with mappings.

```
it.only('putMapping', function (done) {
    client.indices.create({
        index: "aname",
        body: {
            "mappings": {
                "aType": {
                    "properties": {
                        "aProp1": {"type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed"},
                        "aProp2": {"type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed"},
                        "aProp3": {"type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed"},
                        "aProp4": {"type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed"}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }, function (err, resp, respcode) {
        console.log(err, resp, respcode);
    });
})
```

Output:

```
Elasticsearch DEBUG: 2015-08-08T15:23:09Z
  starting request { method: 'POST',
    path: '/aname',
    body: { mappings: { aType: [Object] } },
    query: {} }


Elasticsearch TRACE: 2015-08-08T15:23:10Z
  -> POST http://localhost:9200/aname
  {
    "mappings": {
      "aType": {
        "properties": {
          "aProp1": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "aProp2": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "aProp3": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "aProp4": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  <- 200
  {
    "acknowledged": true
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Just add body around mappings:

```
client.indices.create({
    index: "aName",
    body: {
        "mappings": {
            "aType": {
                "properties": {
                    "aProp1": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
                    "aProp2": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
                    "aProp3": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
                    "aProp4": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, function (err, resp, respcode) {
    console.log(err, resp, respcode);
});
```

Answer (score 11):

None of these examples worked for me on ElasticSearch 5.3 API.

Here is an example that works for 5.3.

```
elasticClient.indices.putMapping({
    index: indexName,
    type: "document",
    body: {
        properties: {
            title: { type: "string" },
            content: { type: "string" },
            suggest: {
                type: "completion",
                analyzer: "simple",
                search_analyzer: "simple",
                payloads: true
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Note that the type has been pulled out of the body, and only the sub-params that were under the type are now in the body.

Source: https://blog.raananweber.com/2015/11/24/simple-autocomplete-with-elasticsearch-and-node-js/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment this is the right answer

Comment: how can I create a index with multiple types

Comment: but as of 7.3 you need to add include_type_name:true

Answer (score 2):

Note: this uses **`client.indices.create()`** and not `client.indices.putMapping()`

I recently succeeded in creating an index with a custom mapping like this:

```
client.indices.create({
  index: 'yourIndex',
  body: {
    yourIndex: {
      mappings: {
        yourType: {
          properties: {
            yourText: {
              type: 'string',
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

It seems you have to start defining the body with your index, followed by the `mappings` keyword, followed by your type and so forth. I used the elasticsearch package version `15.4.1` with elastic version `6.5.4`

Answer (score 1):

Body property is deprecated after version `8.2.1`. Mapping should be set directly in parameters.

```
 await client.indices.create({
    index: "user",
    mappings: {
        properties: {
            "name": {
                type: "text",
                index: true
            },
            "surname": {
                type: "text",
                index: true
            }
        }
    }
});
```