# Error while updating an index in elasticsearch

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, elasticsearch

```
'{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"invalid_type_name_exception","reason":"Document mapping type name can\'t start with \'_\', found: [_update]"}],"type":"invalid_type_name_exception","reason":"Document mapping type name can\'t start with \'_\', found: [_update]"},"status":400}',
```

Getting the above error as a response on making update request in elasticsearch while updating an index with elasticsearch, while below is the JSON data I'm passing.

```
 { name: 'TESTIN ONE (3)',
  id: 'PUZb8739273HD83DGE',
  titles:
   [ { id: 21, title: 'FALSELY ACCUSED' },
     { id: 21, title: 'FALSELY ACCUSED' },
     { id: 23, title: undefined } ] }
```

Also this the function I'm passing through

```
updateProjectIndex = async (project) => {
    try {
        const result = await client.update({
            index: "updatedproject",
            type: "_doc",
            id: project.id,
            refresh: 'true',
            body: project,
        });
        return result;
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

And in this function's parameter I'm passing above JSON.

Error

```
"error": {
      "root_cause": [
        {
          "type": "document_missing_exception",
          "reason": "[_doc][5d8de6a0806590a27895f971]: document missing",
          "index_uuid": "j26lRI1UTJuJmHw_GuPSxg",
          "shard": "0",
          "index": "docprojectnew"
        }
      ],
      "type": "document_missing_exception",
      "reason": "[_doc][5d8de6a0806590a27895f971]: document missing",
      "index_uuid": "j26lRI1UTJuJmHw_GuPSxg",
      "shard": "0",
      "index": "docprojectnew"
    },
    "status": 404   }
```

Value of `project`

```
{ projectName:
   'NEW UPDATE DATA (3)',
  id: '5d8de6a0806590a27895f971',
  titles:
   [ { id: 5d88afc8e9896c1ca7f2c065, title: 'FALSELY ACCUSED' },
     { id: 5d88afc8e9896c1ca7f2c065, title: 'FALSELY ACCUSED' },
     { id: 5d5eeb2ec300364d48764f78, title: undefined } ] }
```

Comment: type: "_doc" . Can you try doc instead of _doc  and see if it works

Comment: @jaspreetchahal Same Issue

Comment: @Farhan, can you try and remove the "type" parameter from the update function and try?

Comment: @AbhilashBolla did that too, but no luck

Comment: @jaspreetchahal `[UpdateRequest] unknown field [name], parser not found`

got this error in latest

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
const result = await client.update({
   index: "updatedproject",
   type: "_doc",
   id: project.id,
   refresh: 'true',
   body: {
     doc: project
   }
});
return result;
```

Comment: `[UpdateRequest] unknown field [name], parser not found`

Comment: @Farhan can you paste the full error and  value of project

Comment: updated details of error and value of project in question

Comment: As per "document missing exception" --document you are trying to update doesnot exist. you can use  doc_as_upsert: true to update doc if present else create one

Comment: Just asking if the ES index updated, it adds new projectName field, and old one stays as it is? 
Is it correct, It should alter the existing one right?

Comment: And in same thing can you help me with deleting the same thing from ES index? Like can you update your answer with deleting the index?

Comment: It will alter the existing field. doc_as_upsert: true creates entire doc if existing _id is not present. Ex you are updating doc with id :1 if it exists , same will be updated, if not present then it is created.

Comment: For delete use client.delete({
  id: string,
  index: string,
  type: string,
  wait_for_active_shards: string,
  refresh: 'true' | 'false' | 'wait_for',
  routing: string,
  timeout: string,
  if_seq_no: number,
  if_primary_term: number,
  version: number,
  version_type: 'internal' | 'external' | 'external_gte' | 'force'
}) . You can get details in here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#_delete

Comment: but it seems like `id` is already there but again its creating new ones.

Comment: can you add mapping of your index

Comment: I have not created mapping, Wher it needs to be created?

`createProjectIndex = async (project) => {
    try {
        await client.index({
            id: project.id,
            index: constants.searchIndexes.project,
            body: {
                doc: project
              },
            type: "_doc",
            refresh: true
        });
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}`
here I directly create index

Comment: When mapping is not given elastic search will automatically infer one ex it will store date as text in place of "date" so good practice is to give one explicitly. Regarding update I am sure it will not create multiple documents can you confirm in kibana if it indeed duplicates are being created

Comment: Just a question where to create this mapping thing? I've shared `createProjectIndex` function so in this function I have to create mappings?

Comment: client.indices.create({
  index: string,
  include_type_name: boolean,
  wait_for_active_shards: string,
  timeout: string,
  master_timeout: string,
  body: object   ----> mapping object
}).  mapping detials you can find here  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html

Comment: What about update function is it working correctly?

Comment: Its creating new entities rather than altering the existing one

Comment: can you check for id field , if it is getting passed as blank then it will create new. Also make sure if existing id is present. Ex if you are passing id as 1 then is that document present , you can check in kibana with GET indexname/_doc/<docid> before running your update query

Comment: Okay,I'll figure that out, but can tell me that where to add mapping?

Comment: while creating index you need to pass it in body . This question has the details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22325708/elasticsearch-create-index-with-mappings-using-javascript

Comment: is there any way to avoid `body: {
     doc: project
   }` and use direct `body:project`

Comment: I'm still struggling with creating mappings

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58134735/creating-mapping-fo-data-and-then-indexing-it-causing-error

check this

Answer (score 0):

What version of Elasticsearch are you using? is the client version compatible with it?

`Document mapping type name can\'t start with \'_\'` suggests, that you are using Elastic prior to 7.0*, but your type: "_doc" would be appropriate for 7.*.

See [Removal of mapping types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/removal-of-types.html)